# how to set access rights of group-mananger and group-user on single view and action in odoo

Tags: odoo

I am working access rights in odoo so trying to apply manager and user access rights on same view and action. is it possible to apply access rights on same (view) which belongs to both group-manager and group-user but having access right different?

Answer (score 0):

You can give view/action access rites to more then one group.

```xml
<record id="view_order_form_editable_list" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">sale.order.form.editable.list</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
    <field name="groups_id" eval="[(4, ref('product.group_uos')), (4, ref('product.group_stock_packaging')), (4, ref('sale.group_mrp_properties'))]"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="editable"/>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

**You can give any number of group in group_id tab**